# RegEx - how to get substring before and behind a certain char in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

For example, I have this string: "request:FLTMODE6"

and i want to remove ":FLTMODE6" to get "request" and remove "request:" to get "FLTMODE6"

Im working with NodeJs, how could this be done?

Answer (score 2):

How about using split instead of regex like `"request:FLTMODE6".split(':')`